# Running a query against an Azure storage table returns 403 AuthenticationFailed, but returning all entries in a table returns 200 OK

Tags: powershell, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-authentication, shared-access-signatures

I am unable to query storage tables using [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/querying-tables-and-entities).

Here is the function I am using to get a shared key in order to authenticate against the Azure storage table.

```
function Get-SharedKeyLiteAuthHeader {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $TRUE)]
        [String]
        $StorageAccount,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $TRUE)]
        [String]
        $TableName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $TRUE)]
        [String]
        $AccessKey,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $FALSE)]
        [String]
        $Version = "2020-04-08"
    )
    $GMTTime = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().toString('R')
    $StringToSign = "$GMTTime`n/$($StorageAccount)/$($TableName)"
    $Hmacsha = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
    $Hmacsha.key = [Convert]::FromBase64String($AccessKey)
    $Signature = $Hmacsha.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($StringToSign))
    $Signature = [Convert]::ToBase64String($Signature)

    return @{
        'x-ms-date'    = $GMTTime
        Authorization  = "SharedKeyLite " + $StorageAccount + ":" + $Signature
        "x-ms-version" = $Version
        Accept         = "application/json;odata=fullmetadata"
    }
}
```

Here is the REST call I am making that returns all table entries & returns a status code of 200.

```
$Uri = "https://$($StorageAccount).table.core.windows.net/$($TableName)"
$Headers = Get-SharedKeyLiteAuthHeader -StorageAccount $StorageAccount -TableName $TableName -AccessKey $AccessKey

$AllEntries = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $Uri -Headers $Headers -ContentType application/json
```

Here is the REST call I am making that returns 403 AuthenticationFailed.

```
$Uri = "https://$($StorageAccount).table.core.windows.net/$($TableName)()?$top=2"
$Headers = Get-SharedKeyLiteAuthHeader -StorageAccount $StorageAccount -TableName $TableName -AccessKey $AccessKey

$SomeEntries = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $Uri -Headers $Headers -ContentType application/json
```

My end goal is to [filter by date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/querying-tables-and-entities#filtering-on-datetime-properties), but I can't get any of the query parameters working. I suspect it has to do with missing header elements, but I can't pin down what those might be as [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-tables#request-headers) that discusses the header elements required lists all of the elements that I have already specified.

Any help is appreciated - thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the URL, just delete the `()` :

```
https://$($StorageAccount).table.core.windows.net/$($TableName)?$top=2
```

[image]

---

I tried with the your code, it return `AuthenticationFailed`.

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"odata.error":{"code":"AuthenticationFailed","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization 
header is formed correctly including the signature.
```

Maybe you will change `StringToSign` when getting this error. However, it is correct and no need to add query string, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key#shared-key-lite-and-table-service-format-for-2009-09-19-and-later).

> The query string should include the question mark and the comp
> parameter (for example, ?comp=metadata). **No other parameters should be
> included on the query string.**

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but while it does get rid of the `AuthenticationFailed` error, it doesn't actually filter the results for me. Calling without the `()` in the URL returns all of the entries in the table, rather than just the values specified in the filter. Are you seeing filtered results when you run the same code?

Comment: Ah, you know what, your answer works! The only thing missing is the $ in the URL. It needs to be formatted as:
```"https://$($StorageAccount).table.core.windows.net/$($TableName)?`$top=1"```
(Notice the extra tick before the dollar sign...`$)
Thank you very much!